# How to connect a MySql database to an ASP Net Core application?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am making an API and I'm using Entity Framework and migrating from a Sqlite database to a MySql database hosted on Azure, I found this part of the documentation for MySql : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core.html
It was useful, I added it to my code which now looks like this :

```
    namespace APILeaderboardProjectCallback.Data
    {
    public class MySqlContext : DbContext
    {
     public DbSet\<Level\> Levels { get; set; }
     public DbSet\<Player\> Players { get; set; }
     public DbSet\<Try\> Tries { get; set; }
     public DbSet\<Morality\> Moralities { get; set; }
     public DbSet\<MoralAction\> MoralActions { get; set; }
     public DbSet\<MoralActionUsage\> MoralActionUsages { get; set; }
     private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        
     public MySqlContext(IConfiguration configuration)

       {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
    
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            => optionsBuilder.UseMySQL( _configuration.GetConnectionString("db"));
    }

}
```

But it doesn't say what to do next, I tried to type "Add-Migration InitialCreate" like with Sqlite, but throw this error :

```
Method not found: 'System.String Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.RelationalStrings.get_NoConnectionOrConnectionString()'.
```

I tried not to do anything but then any request to my controllers throw this error :

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.String Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.RelationalStrings.get_NoConnectionOrConnectionString()'.
```

I tried to look at other tutorial but a lot of them mentions the Startup.cs which doesn't exist on my code because I use Asp Net Core version 6, So I tried to add this to my program.cs :

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext\<MySqlContext\>(
options =\> options.UseMySQL(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("db"))
);
```

Here is an extract of csproj file with all the NuGet Packages I have :

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.8.116" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLiteNetExtensions" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Here is my appsetting.json with the connection string file (minus the password), am I doing something wrong here ?

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "db": "server=callback-leaderboard-db.mysql.database.azure.com;database=callback_leaderboard;user=jauclair4;password=[my password]"
  }
}
```

But it doesn't seems to help. Could this error means my connection string is invalid ?

Comment: have u added the required NuGet packages ?

Comment: I updated my post to include my csproj file with all the NuGet packages I currently have

Comment: Try to install this Nuget package: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` and then migrate: `Add-Migration InitialCreate  Update-Database`. Make sure your connection string is correct.